# Make SQL SERVER evaluate clauses in a certain order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Take the following table as an instance:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_Names(Name VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO TBL_Names
VALUES ('Ken'),('1965'),('Karen'),('2541')
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb)

Executing following query throws an exception:

```
SELECT  [name]
FROM    dbo.tblNames AS tn
WHERE   [name] IN ( SELECT  [name]
                    FROM    dbo.tblNames
                    WHERE   ISNUMERIC([name]) = 1 )
        AND [name] = 2541
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
> the varchar value 'Ken' to data type int.

While the following query executes without error:

```
SELECT  [name]
FROM    dbo.tblNames AS tn
WHERE   ISNUMERIC([name]) = 1
        AND [name] = 2541
```

I know that this is because of SQL Server Query Optimizer's decision. but I am wondering if there is any way to make sql server evaluate clauses in a certain order. this way, in the first query,the first clause filters out those `Names` that are not numeric so that the second clause will not fail at converting to a number.

**Update:** As you may noticed, the above query is just an instance to exemplify the problem. I know the risks of that implicit conversion and appreciate those who tried to warn me of that. However my main question is how to change Optimizer's behavior of evaluating clauses in a certain order.

Comment: Just a punt. But have you tried a WITH clause for the nested select instead to see if it still throws an error?

Comment: I recommend against `ISNUMERIC` as it gives false positives. For example `ISNUMERIC('.')` returns true, however, `CONVERT(int,'.')` will fail. I suggest `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no *"direct"* way of telling the engine to perform operations in order. SQL isn't an imperative language where you have complete control of ***how*** to do things, you simply tell ***what*** you need and the server decides how to do it itself.

For this particular case, as long as you have `[name] = 2541`, you are risking a potential conversion failure since you are comparing a `VARCHAR` column against an `INT`. Even if you use a subquery/CTE there is still room for the optimizer to evaluate this expression first and try to convert all varchar values to int (thus failing).

You can evade this with workarounds:

- Correctly comparing matching data types:

  ```
  [name] = '2541'
  ```
- Casting `[name]` to `INT` beforehand and only whenever possible and on *a different statement*, do the comparison.

  ```
  DECLARE @tblNamesInt TABLE (nameInt INT)

  INSERT INTO @tblNamesInt (
      nameInt)
  SELECT
      [nameInt] = CONVERT(INT, [name])
  FROM    
      dbo.tblNames
  WHERE   
      TRY_CAST([name] AS INT) IS NOT NULL -- TRY_CAST better than ISNUMERIC for INT


  SELECT
      *
  FROM
      @tblNamesInt AS T
  WHERE
      T.nameInt = 2351 -- data types match
  ```

Even an index hint won't force the optimizer to use an index (that's why it's called a hint), so we have little control on how it gets stuff done.

---

There are a few mechanics that we *know* are evaluated in order and we can use to our advantage, such as the `HAVING` expressions will always be computed after grouping values, and the grouping always after `WHERE` conditions. So we can "safely" do the following grouping:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (IntsAsVarchar VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Table (IntsAsVarchar)
VALUES
    ('1'), 
    ('2'),
    ('20'),
    ('25'),
    ('30'),

    ('A') -- Not an INT!

SELECT
    CASE WHEN T.IntsAsVarchar < 15 THEN 15 ELSE 30 END,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    @Table AS T
WHERE
    TRY_CAST(T.IntsAsVarchar AS INT) IS NOT NULL -- Will filter out non-INT values first
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN T.IntsAsVarchar < 15 THEN 15 ELSE 30 END
```

But you should always avoid writing code that implies implicit conversions (like `T.IntsAsVarchar < 15`).

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tblNames AS tn
WHERE [name] = convert(varchar, 2541)
```

Why do you need `ISNUMERIC([name]) = 1)` since you only care about the value `'2541'`?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
  SELECT  [name]
    FROM    #TBL_Names AS tn
    WHERE   [name] IN ( SELECT  [name]
                        FROM    #TBL_Names
                        WHERE   ISNUMERIC([name]) = 1 )
            AND  [name] = '2541'
```

2)

```
AND  [name] =  convert(varchar,2541 )
```

Since You are storing name as varchar(32) varchar will accept integer datatype values also called precedence value

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT  [name]
FROM    dbo.TBL_Names AS tn
WHERE   [name] IN ( SELECT  [name]
                    FROM    dbo.TBL_Names
                    WHERE   ISNUMERIC([name]) = 1 )
        AND [name] = '2541'
```

You need to just `[name] = 2541` to `[name] = '2541'`. You are missing `'` (single quote) with name in where condition.

You can find the live demo [Here](https://rextester.com/TVYK22662).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I wouldn't apply the implicit cast to your column `[name]`, it'll make the query non-SARGable. Instead, convert the value of your input (or pass it as a string)

```
SELECT [name]
FROM dbo.TBL_Names tn
WHERE [name] = CONVERT(varchar(32),2541);
```

If you "*must*", however, wrap `[name]` (and suffer performance degradation) then use `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM dbo.TBL_Names tn
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int,[name]) = 2541;
```